# Pass value from autoit.exe to java program

Tags: autoit

Hi i need to return a value(String) from the autoit.exe to java program(The program which is calling the autoit.exe). So please help me to return value. Below is the code for - Autoit script where i am trying to read a value from the combo box which i am reading correctly. Then i return the value.

```
Main()

Func Main()

Local Const $dialogTitle = $CmdLine[1]
Local Const $timeout = 5
Local $OTHERARGS= $CmdLine[1]
Local $windowFound = WinWait($dialogTitle, "", $timeout)

Local $windowHandle

If $windowFound Then
    $windowHandle = WinGetHandle("[LAST]")
    WinActivate($windowHandle)
     Local $sString = ControlGetText("","","[CLASS:Edit;INSTANCE:1]")
    ControlClick($windowHandle, "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:&Cancel]")
    Return $sString
  Else
    Exit(1)
EndIf
EndFunc
```

This code is working fine as it is returning 0 as a process exit value. However i am not able to get the return string value. Below is the code for java:

```
String exePath = "D:\\amit\\Documents\\CancelSave.exe";
exePath = exePath.replace("//", "\\");
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(exePath,""+windowName).start();

// get the input stream of the process and print it
InputStream in = process.getInputStream();

for (int i = 0; i < in.available(); i++) {
 System.out.println("" + in.read());//Here it print nothing

 }
```

Comment: Please add some example code to demonstrate and show what you've already tried and what part you are getting stuck on.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot use a string as the exit code. Returning $sString there probably just causes the process to return 0 or 1 as the exit code. You may want to write the value to the standard output stream (not sure if its possible) and capture it via java.

Comment: Exit can only set Integer values. You can create a mapping in your Java program. 1 = ok 2 = Ok, but 3 = Found nothing, ... You could write the value to memory or file or ... and read it with java from there

Answer (score 3):

[ConsoleWrite ( "data" )](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ConsoleWrite.htm) writes a string to STDOUT. So instead returning a value from your AutoIt script you should write the value to STDOUT and exit the AutoIt script, then read the value with a stream reader.